# How to remove empty space in top/bottom of span?

Tags: html, css

This is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4fuLfq5f/2/). I want to remove empty space in top and bottom in my text. I tried to use line-height, but its not what I need. How I can do it? Thanks.

```
span {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
}
```

[image]

Comment: why not line height? do you see any issue with that approach..?

Comment: What values for line height did you try?

Comment: Use - margin:0; and padding:0;

Comment: Line height works, but I thought that exists another solution..

Comment: It is depending on the font you are using

Comment: @Gunaseelan Interesting... recently I've found that 9 of 10 questions here have been answered earlier.

Comment: @HashemQolami People finds easy to ask a question rather than looking for similar questions that already solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not ideal, however you could play with `height` and `line-height` to achieve that:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700);
span {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: 'Roboto';

    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: .75em;
    line-height: .75em;

    background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<span>Some Text</span>
```