# How to remove vertical spacing in <span> element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I remove the vertical blank space from the top and bottom of this  element?  The text and text size are dynamic so I can't hard code a value in the css.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440174/how-to-remove-empty-space-in-top-bottom-of-span?

Comment: What vertical blank space, inside the red area or the lines below it or what? Why not add an example instead of an image ?

Comment: Thanks Hashem, yes, it is the same question but the answers all say to hard code a value for line-height.  Is there any way to remove the vertical space in the red box without hardcoding a value?  The text size dynamically changes so hard coding a value for line-height won't work.

Comment: this is a <span> element

Comment: So  why not change the line-height when the text-size is changed, and set it too dynamically ?

Comment: but change it to what?  it looks like line-height has to be a hard coded value.  if set to the font size then it still has that spacing.

Comment: @BrettHamlin You could try using `em` unit - as I've done - so that it would change with the respect to font-size. However the value may be different from font to font.

Comment: @HashemQolami thanks, I'm using 0.8em, it seems to work for now but I'm weary of relying on a hard coded value.  But if that's the only way to do it then it will have to do.  Thanks everyone for you help.

Comment: Can't think of any other way at the moment. Am not sure if there's any, though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the line-height smaller than the font-size. So if you have football declared in size 50px font, set the line-height to 40px. It will account for the spacing above and below the font chars.

```
p {
font-size: 50px;
background-color: red;
line-height: 40px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nj6tzrnL/